TestCafe > TypeScript> ReferenceError: aut_fe_e2e_core_1 is not defined" How to fix this
TestCafe > TypeScript> while execution got below error " An error occurred in ClientFunction code: ReferenceError: aut_fe_e2e_core_1 is not defined"
seems this is a package error
how to resolve this issue?
I tried to debug the code , not able to proceed much

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
